# How to control Android device with webdriver.io

Tags: android, appium, webdriver-io

I am using [appium-uiautomator2-driver](https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver) to start a server on an Android device with following code

```
const {startServer} = require('appium-uiautomator2-driver')
startServer()
const { AndroidUiautomator2Driver } = require("appium-uiautomator2-driver");

const startDriver = async () => {
  const driver = new AndroidUiautomator2Driver();
  const capabilities = {
    automationName: "UiAutomator2",
    platformName: "Android",
    deviceName: "emulator-5554",
  };
  await driver.createSession(capabilities);
};
startDriver().catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

And then I am trying to connect with webdriver.io to the server running on the device like that:

```
const wdio = require("webdriverio");

const driverPromise = wdio.attach({
  isAndroid: true,
  port: 8213,
  isMobile: true,
  automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
  sessionId: "56667cc9-625e-4e13-8c4d-354d1928d859",
});

driverPromise.then(async function (driver) {
  await driver.touchAction([
    { action: "press", x: 200, y: 200 },
    { action: "moveTo", x: 200, y: 300 },
    "release",
  ]);
});
```

But what I get is an UnknownCommandException:

```
2021-12-09T18:01:20.083Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to unknown command: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
(node:61813) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.UnknownCommandException: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:75)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is? Is the UIAutomator driver incompatible with webdriver.io? It should be, because the [readme.md](https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver) says "The driver operates in scope of W3C WebDriver protocol with several custom extensions to cover operating-system specific scenarios."

Comment: Did you get it to work? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest do not use uiautomator2 directly, because it's designed to be an internal part of Appium.

Webdriver.io supports Appium protocol. uiautomator2 could be used if corresponding `automationName` capability will be passed.
https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate/blob/main/config/wdio.android.app.conf.ts

Please, look at the android native project template:
https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate/.

Comment: Didn't manage to get webdriver.io working with the appium server. Not even using the config from the boilerplate.

Comment: What do you mean by "use uiautomator2 directly"?

Comment: You are trying to create a separate uiautomator2 driver session using uiautomator2-driver lib and then attach. I suggest to create a new appium session with "UIAutomator2" capability with wdio.remote like in this example: http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/index.html.